# deserializing object with arraylist of booleans returning incorect boolean values

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

Iam currently creating an application for an alarm clock on android and Ive run into an issue I am hoping someone on here can clarify. Basically I serialize some objects and save to file. these objects each contain an arraylist of type boolean. representing the days the alarm should go off. I sem to be able to read in and out the serialized "alarm_entity" object fine but I have one issue. Once the "alarm_entity" objects are deserialized, the arraylist within each object seems to be returning the boolean values at certain indices incorrectly. an example would be 1. i save the state of the days in  checkboxes representing the days of the week 2. restart the device. then open the app  and the booleans are represented incorrectly in the GUI. Say for example, I had an alarm and set the days to be "monday" and "thursday" in the relevant checkboxes, on restart the checkboxes my be set on "monday" and "friday". below is my "alarm_entity" class which gets serialized.

```
public class alarm_entity implements Serializable {


private boolean state;
private boolean repeating;
private int hours;
private int mins;
private ArrayList<Boolean> days;
private final int numdays = 7;


 public alarm_entity(int hoursin, int minsin)
{

    days = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    state = true;
    repeating = false;
    hours = hoursin;
    mins = minsin;
    initDays();
}


private void initDays()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numdays; i++)
    {
        boolean temp = false;
        days.add(i, temp);
    }
}

public void setDay(int pos, boolean state)
{
    days.add(pos, state);
}

public ArrayList<Boolean> getDays()
{
   return days;
}




public int getMins()
{
    return mins;
}

public void setMins(int minsin)
{
    mins = minsin;
}

public boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public int getHours()
{
   return hours;
}

public void setHours(int hoursin)
{
    hours = hoursin;
}

public void setState(boolean statein)
{
    state = statein;
}

public boolean getState()
{
    return state;
}
}
```

I have tried testing this code in a unit test it seems to work fine and booleans are deserialized as the same as when they were saved.

below is the method i use to write the alarm objects

```
@Override
public synchronized void writeToFile(final ArrayList<alarm_entity> alarmlist) {

    if(alarmfile == null) {

        createFile(Alarm_List.filename);
    }

    try
    {
        fostream = new FileOutputStream(alarmfile);
        oostream = new ObjectOutputStream(fostream);
        addAlarms(alarmlist);

        oostream.close();
        fostream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("error", "write exception");
    }


}

private void addAlarms(final ArrayList<alarm_entity> alarmlist) {

    Thread mythrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(alarm_entity alarm : alarmlist)
            {
                try {
                    oostream.writeObject(alarm);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mythrd.start();



    try {
        mythrd.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("alarms writing", "alarms saved");
}
```

If anyone could shine some light on this for me that would be great as Iam kind of lost with it at the minute. I think the issue may be due to the arraylist within the serialized object. anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you read & represent the data for the UI correctly, ex reading Sunday value and save it as Friday data

Comment: iam 100% on the checkboxes representing the correct boolean.

Comment: The thread is completely pointless. You can replace the `addAlarms()` call and the entire method with `oostream.writeObject(alarmlist);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setDay(int pos, boolean state)` is incorrect.

You are using `days.add(pos, state);` this method insert the data at that position.
To replace use `days.set(pos, state);` instead.

Check out the doc [List.set(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) and [List.add(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)